# Views aren't updated after modifications - Play Framework 2

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0, refresh

I work on a project with Play2 framework, and before my modifications on my views were displayed, but now it doesn't work anymore... I've cleared all caches, restart server, execute "play ~run" command, but nothing..

Have you any ideas why my website don't refresh ?

(I work with Scala)

Comment: Please post full source code

Answer (score 1):

Just look around your controller codes . You might have mistaken on any "Redirect" links also check for the routes file .. All the best!!!!!

Comment: I stopped my server and run "play clean compile" command and that have refresh my views. Thank you anyway.